# May a pupil request that a different teaching method be used and/or the content rearranged for his comprehension?

Tags: adult-learning

To paint a scenario, a process is somewhat regulated by an outside authority on what needs to be taught, understood and implemented. The teaching arm of this authority is allowed to arrange these how they wish or see fit and devises a structure, which they then disseminate to their teachers. They also semi-frequently change the curriculum structure.

If a pupil does not find easy comprehension or finds it to be ill suited to their learning style or method, may he - with halachic and/or hashkafa backing - ask for the content to be rearranged and/or ask for changes in the teaching method?

I am pulling this question from [this](http://www.myjewishlearning.com/texts/Bible/Weekly_Torah_Portion/toldot_hillel5761.shtml?p=0) article, which covers some of the textual backings / analysis.

---

Edited to include the note that this is all within the Jewish community and Jewish organizations.

Comment: I see you've tagged this "adult learning", so I assume you mean adults and not kids?  Are you talking about group instruction (where changes affect others) or individual tutoring?

Comment: What exactly are you asking... You can certainly ask for anything and whatever that will help you learn and understand the material. If the institution can't accommodate you at least you tried.